# Prevent page jumping when DOM element collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Let's say I am on a website page, with a form and a radio selection, as below
[image]

When website user select one of these radio buttons, an JS function will be triggered to collapse the radio button module. And in the meantime, a lot calculation is running behind the screen.

The problem is, when the network speed is slow, especially on a mobile device, after the radio button is selected, it might take 5 seconds or even more to collapse the radio module.

Image this: My user click one radio button, the module is running calculation on the background, user continue to the form section, now user only see the form section on his phone, and at this point of time, **my module collapse. User will see the form content jumping up,** no longer in his viewpoint.

What I want to achieve is, the user's view of the page stays the same, even when the module above collapse, the user should still stay where he was like nothing happens above.

How to do that?

My thought is:

1. When the module is about to collapse, trigger a JS function.
2. The JS function should be able to mark down current user's viewpoint location on the page.
3. The JS function should then make the viewpoint stay at the same location, despite of content above shrink or expand.
4. The JS function should be bale to use on all browser support, mobile devices.
5. The JS function should not break accessibility.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `element.getBoundingClientRect()` method to get the position of a specific element on the screen, and then the `scrollBy` method to move the screen to that element.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the wrong plan here.  The user does not care when the selection is successfully sent to the server; only when the selection is successfully received by the webpage.  That is, when the user selects an option, the module should IMMEDIATELY collapse.

Your website can send the data to the server while the module is collapsing, or even after the module has finished collapsing; the user will not care.